# jar dependencies(available in the POM file ) are not added to the war file.

Tags: maven, jar, war

I'm creating a base framework and distributing it as a jar file. Other developers will use this jar in the web application. others are going to use **mvn install:install-file** to install the jar in the local repository.

if i try to use the jar in the war , the jar dependencies(jar contains the POM file) are not available in the war. Then i included the pom file in the install command then it worked correctly. 
**mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-file -DpomFile=path-to-pomfile** 
The jar file already contains pom file with dependencies,Then why do i need to include the pom file in the install command explicitly.

Is there any alternate ways to pull the dependency available in the jar(POM file) to the war file. otherwise unnecessarly i have to provide the jar and POM file to others.

Thanks,
Sampath

Answer (score 0):

The war project should have its own POM file specifying a dependency on your jar project. In this way, when you build the war, your jar and all its dependencies would be pulled into the war automatically.

In order to distribute artifacts among your fellow developers you should install a repository manager, such as [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).

Comment: Hi Nicola, Thanks for your reply. In the war file i have a separate POM file and i have specified dependency on the jar project.Actual issue is, if i try to install the jar in the local repository without specifying the POM file in the install command, i'm not able pull the jar dependencies in the war. The Jar already contains the POM file , why do i need to mention in the install command specifically.

Comment: If your project is structured according to the Maven standards running `mvn install` should cause it to be compiled, packaged into a jar, and installed to your local repository.